# Why my context state is not rendering in my unique component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, use-context

I am redirecting on my unique component and I want my data in my context api to be rendered matching with the params that I passed.

Here is the code to my Component;

```
export default function BasketballScoreboard() {
  const dataContext = useContext(DataContext);

  let { matchId } = useParams();
  let nowMatch = dataContext.liveMatchList.filter(
    (match) => match._id === matchId
  );

  if (!dataContext.isLoaded) {
    return <Grid>Loading...</Grid>;
  } else {
    return <div>{nowMatch}</div>;
  }
}
```

When I log it, it returns an empty array but when I do make something like that to another component like a dashboard it returns the expected data.

Comment: Is the BasketballScoreboard inside the provider? Sounds like it's getting the initial `DataContext`.

Comment: @MichaelHoobler Yes it is inside. All other components are working well except on that component.

Comment: As we cannot reproduce the problem, it will be hard to help you... Can you show us how DataContext is initialized? Is isLoaded true or false?

Comment: I have fixed it, urggh sorry for the inconvenience. I have used a wrong Promise to make it call. But thank you for all your help